# Global variables in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, web

So I was practicing javascript and I wrote the following code

```
function fun1(){
    globalVar = 5;
}
function fun2(){
console.log(globalVar);
}
fun2();
```

I am using vs code and I run the above code using node and it says that globalVar is undefined, I don't understand global variables well so a brief explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't run `fun1()` to assign to the global.

Answer (score 1):

You did not run fun1()

```js
function fun1(){
    globalVar = 5;
}
fun1();
function fun2(){
console.log(globalVar);
}
fun2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing declaration of the `globalVar` variable. Add

```
let globalVar;
```

above the function `fun1()`.

Comment: fun1 is not calling thats why it show undefined, if he set let globalVar; but not run fun1 then still he will get undefined

Answer (score 0):

The fact that in `func2` you have `globalVar = 5;` and not `var|let|const globalVar = 5;` causes JavaScript to treat `globalVar` as a global variable. However, since you do not call `func1`, when `globalVar` is seen in `func2` it is indeed still `undefined`.

If you add a call to `func1` before calling `func2`, then by the time console.log is executed `globalVar` will be defined. Although if you are in strict mode, you will get an error complaining about trying to assign a value to an undefined variable (in `func1`). So, you'd better have a `var globalVar;' at the very top.

So, in essence

- if you have an assignment inside a function and the variable is not preceded with a `var|let|const` qualifier it is assumed to be a variable defined in the global scope,
- if the variable *is* defined in the global scope all is good; if it is not, if you are in strict mode (if your code begins with `"use strict";`), then there will be an error. If you are not in strict mode the variable will be defined in the global scope and execution continues.